# Getting Redux State into Rails Database (Using Rails Webpacker-React)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-redux

So I'm using rails' recent webpacker feature which lets me manage app-like JavaScript modules in Rails with the power of webpack. My project is entirely in Rails (no react-router) with a react component in one of the pages. I've figured out how to get objects from my database to the component so it can render them but I can't figure out how to get data my component creates to my rails database.

I've been doing a lot of searching but to no avail. Most of the articles I'm finding are for getting data from rails to react. I've gotten so far as installing axios-on-rails and putting this in my javascript...

```js
axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/things',
  data: data,
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': document.querySelector("meta[name=csrf-token]").content
  }
})
```

But I have NO idea how to use this. What I want is my react component to POST redux's state on a button click to my rails backend and some how catch that data so I can put it in the database.

Thank you all in advance for your help. Even just some resources to read would be very helpful. My main problem with figuring this out by myself is that I don't know where to start. There is so much information out there.

Comment: `<button onClick={() => axios(...put state here)} />` ?

Comment: @azium okay, so that's a piece of the puzzle. But what do I do with the url attribute? What do I put there? On the rails end, how do I catch the POST?

Comment: you're asking very fundamental questions about web applications. "How do I make a network request from client to server" and "How do I create a REST api?". You need to do some reading...this tutorial looks like it answers all your questions https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-one

Comment: @azium I understand that it is very fundamental. Part of me just wants a quick answer so that I can get on with my project but what you posted is going to be more helpful in the long run. Thank you so much for the resource. It looks promising!

Comment: quick answers to fundamental questions are going to cause you tons of headaches. stackoverflow is a great place to ask very SPECIFIC questions

Comment: @azium You're right. It's worthwhile in the long run. Thank you for your help. I'm going to do the tutorial!